# How to add dependent object to list of objects in rails / rhomobile for HTML page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rhomobile

I'm a bit new to rails/RhoMobile so I can't work out how to add a child object to a parent object so it's available as a member of the instance variable @questions on my form.  Here is my controller method

```
def diary_day_one_morning
  qgroup = "activity_day_one_morning"
   @questions = Question.find(:all, :conditions => { { :name => "qgroup", :op => '=' } => qgroup } )
  # make sure all questions have an answer
  @questions.each do |q|
    a = Answer.find(:all, :conditions => { { :name => "question_id", :op => '=' } => q.object }).first
    if not a
      a = Answer.new
      a.question_id = q.object
      a.save
    end
    #@questions[q].answer = a # here is my issue!!!
  end
  render :action => :diary_day_one_morning, :back => url_for(:action => :index)
end
```

At the @questions[q].answer part I'm a bit lost as to how to make my question joined to the answer.  Then on the form how do I refer to the answer?   Here is what I already have:

```
    <% @questions.each_with_index do |question, qcount| %>
      <div class="ui-block-a">
        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">
          <%= question.qpromptshort %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% a = Answer.find(:all, :conditions => { { :name => "question_id", :op => '=' } => question.object }).first %>

      <% if a %>
        <input type="hidden" id="answer<%=qcount%>[object]" name="answer<%=qcount%>[object]" value="<%=a.object%>" />
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <input type="text" id="answer<%=qcount%>[value1]" name="answer<%=qcount%>[value1]" value="<%=a.value1%>" />
        </div>
   .......
```

I'd prefer to refer to the answer (a) as a member of the question instead of looking it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the index of each object in the @questions array by using the each_with_index method.

```
 @questions.each_with_index do |q,qindex|
    a = Answer.find(:all, :conditions => { { :name => "question_id", :op => '=' } => q.object }).first
    if not a
      a = Answer.new
      a.question_id = q.object
      a.save
    end
    # use qindex to add it back into the @questions array
    @questions[qindex].answer = a 
  end
```

Then in the page the answer will be available as question.answer.